# Find All Records from Customer where ALL their records have NULL value in Price Field

Tags: mysql

Hopefully I can describe this simply if not I'll try to make a table for it: say I have a table that tracks all visits to my store by customer name. I log their Name and Purchase Amount (if any). I want to get a list of visitors who never buy anything.  So if I have

`VisitorName   PurchaseAmount`

`Bob           10`

`Bob           NULL`

`Mary          NULL`

`Mary          NULL`

I want a query that returns `Mary` since all of her records have `NULL` in the `PurchaseAmount`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a not in subselect the VisitorName that have value not null

```
select distinct visitorName from my_table  
 where visitorName not in ( select VisitorName 
                     from my_table where PurchaseAmount is not null)
```

Comment: Interesting is the middle select works fine but the outer select gets an empty set. I manually checked and there are many Customers where all the Orders are NULL so it is not the data.

Comment: explain better  .. this query is simple so you can easy test .. if don't work  show me the involved   value  ..     ,(check if you have empty value (not null)

Comment: I was going to delete my above comment when I found my error but figured it could be helpful to someone in the future; I had a record where the CustomerName was `NULL` which resulted in the Empty Set from the outer-select, it works great now thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Create table/insert data**

```
CREATE TABLE visits
    (`VisitorName` VARCHAR(4), `PurchaseAmount` VARCHAR(4))
;

INSERT INTO visits
    (`VisitorName`, `PurchaseAmount`)
VALUES
    ('Bob', '10'),
    ('Bob', NULL),
    ('Mary', NULL),
    ('Mary', NULL)
;
```

**Query**

Just GROUP BY on VisitorName. 
And a HAVING what checks if all records are NULL's

```
SELECT 
 visits.VisitorName
FROM 
 visits
GROUP BY
  visits.VisitorName 
HAVING 
 SUM(CASE
       WHEN visits.PurchaseAmount IS NULL
       THEN 1
    END
 ) = COUNT(*)
```

**Result**

```
VisitorName  
-------------
Mary
```